# Spark Jobserver max-jobs-per-context

Tags: spark-jobserver

How would you determine a safe max threshold value for the max-jobs-per-context setting, which controls the number of concurrent Spark jobs that are running on a context?  What would happen if you go too high? The default is set to 8 (see link below), and I'd like to set it higher, but I'm not sure what happens if you set it too high.

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/main/resources/application.conf

Answer (score 2):

An approach that we are using in production is to put a queue in front of spark jobserver and control job submission. There is no inbuilt queuing mechanism in SJS.